# How to mix center alignment and left alignment in HTML

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a design for a top-of-the-page dashboard in HTML that has the following requirements:

- Everything should be vertically centered within the dashboard.
- It should have a button in the exact center.
- It should have text centered at the 25% and 75% marks.
- It should have one last group of text all the way to the left.

Like this, but not with horrible colors:

[image: Like this, but not with horrible colors.]

I was able to achieve the top three goals (or very close to it) using `display: flex` and giving appropriate sizes to everything, like so:

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <span class="left-text">LEFT TEXT</span>
    <button class="button">BUTTON</button>
    <span class="right-text">RIGHT TEXT</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: beige;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.button {
    height: 26px;
    width: 100px;
    order: 2;
    flex-grow: 0;
}

.left-text {
    order: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

.right-text {
    order: 3;
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
```

This last requirement, though, is really throwing me for a loop; without everything being nice and centered, I feel like `flex` is going to need some ugly adjustments. I feel like this would be much easier if I could layer `div` or `span` elements on top of each other however I liked, but something tells me I can't. Are there any good solutions for this problem? Am I close?

EDIT: added image of mockup.

Comment: Could you give us a simple visual mock-up of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I can when I get back from lunch.

Comment: What is the problem here https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/238/?

Comment: @NenadVracar the other elements are no longer centered. Most importantly, the button is no longer right in the center of the page.

Comment: Maybe something like this but you would have to fix it with media queries https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/239/

Comment: I guess your navbar is collapsing on tablet size anyway.

Comment: Well this isn't really an application designed for mobile anyhow, so I don't think that's a huge deal.

Comment: You may find this answer helpful: [Methods for Aligning Flex Items](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)

Comment: @NenadVracar I ended up using your solution with the translate item, but for every element in the header. What do you mean by fixing it with media queries?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will work for you, basically it adds the `more-left` class and positions it relative to the `header`, and you move it to the left as necessary, whatever is fitting.

## HTML

```
<div class="header">
    <span class="more-left">MORE LEFT</span>
    <span class="left-text">LEFT TEXT</span>
    <button class="button">BUTTON</button>
    <span class="right-text">RIGHT TEXT</span>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: beige;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.button {
    height: 26px;
    width: 100px;
    order: 2;
    flex-grow: 0;
}

.left-text {
    order: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

.right-text {
    order: 3;
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
.more-left {
    position: relative;
    left: 15%; /* adjust as neccessary */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up ditching Flexbox entirely, going with absolute positioning and `translate` in order to get the results I wanted. Here's the final code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
    <span class="more-left v-center">MORE LEFT</span>
    <span class="left-text abs-center">LEFT TEXT</span>
    <button class="button abs-center">BUTTON</button>
    <span class="right-text abs-center">RIGHT TEXT</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: beige;
}

.v-center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.h-center {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.abs-center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.button {
    height: 26px;
    width: 100px;
    left: 50%;
}

.more-text {
    left: 10px;
}

.left-text {
    left: 25%;
}

.right-text {
    left: 75%;
}
```

EDIT: it occurred to me that you can't really combine `v-center` and `h-center`, because one of the `transform` entries will completely overwrite the other, instead of combining them. Hence the `abs-center` class.